# How send and receive a enum parameter?

Tags: c#, dynamic, enums

How send and receive a enum parameter?
I have several type enum and I want to make a generic method to get of descriptions

```
 public enum Lista_Size
 {
   [Description("Chica")] Chica,
   [Description("Grande")] Grande,
   [Description("Extra Grande")] Extra_Grande,
 }

 public enum Lista_Color
 {
   [Description("Verde")] Verde,
   [Description("Blanco Perla")] Blanco,
   [Description("Rojo Fuerte")] Rojo_Strong,
 }
```

I have this method to get description

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> Descripcion_Referencia(Enum Referencia)
    {
        var Descripcion = new List<string>();
        var Tipo = Referencia.GetType();
        var Nombre = Enum.GetName(Tipo, Referencia);
        var Campo = Tipo.GetField(Nombre);
        var Campo_Descripcion = Campo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);
        foreach(DescriptionAttribute Atributo in Campo_Descripcion)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Atributo.Description: " + Atributo.Description);
            Descripcion.Add(Atributo.Description);
        }
        return Descripcion;
    }
```

And I have other two method that call de method Descripcion_Referencia, this method I want to make it generic. I want call it some that: Cargar_Combo(Lista_Color); or Cargar_Combo(Lista_Size) 
but if I write public void Cargar_Combo(enum Lista) it indicate like mistake ¿How I have to send it or receive it?

```
    public void Cargar_Combo()
    {
        DataTable Dt_Combo = new DataTable();
        Dt_Combo.Columns.Add("Value");
        Dt_Combo.Columns.Add("Descripcion");
        DataRow Dr_Combo = Dt_Combo.NewRow();
        IEnumerable<string> Resultado;

        Type Tipo = typeof(Gral_Constantes.Cat_Uti_Formatos_Apartados.Referencia_Catalogo_Sistema);
        String[] Lista = Tipo.GetEnumNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Length; i++ )
        {
            Resultado = Descripcion_Referencia((Gral_Constantes.Cat_Uti_Formatos_Apartados.Referencia_Catalogo_Sistema)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gral_Constantes.Cat_Uti_Formatos_Apartados.Referencia_Catalogo_Sistema), Lista[i]));
            Dr_Combo = Dt_Combo.NewRow();
            Dr_Combo["Value"] = Lista[i];
            Dr_Combo["Descripcion"] = Resultado.ElementAt(0);
            Dt_Combo.Rows.Add(Dr_Combo);

        }
        Cmb_Catalogo.DataSource = Dt_Combo;
        Cmb_Catalogo.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
        Cmb_Catalogo.ValueMember = "Value";

    }
```

Ok . I did it with the Enum Type parameterName but now Type = typeof ( Parameter ) does not recognize the name of the parameter and underlines it in red.

```
    public DataTable Cargar_Combo(Enum Parametro)
    {
        DataTable Dt_Referencia = new DataTable();
        Dt_Referencia.Columns.Add("Nombre");
        Dt_Referencia.Columns.Add("Descripcion");
        DataRow Dr_Referencia = Dt_Referencia.NewRow();
        IEnumerable<string> Resultado;


        Type Tipo = typeof(Parametro); //Here error mark , does not recognize the name of the parameter
        String[] Lista = Tipo.GetEnumNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Length; i++)
        {

            Resultado = Descripcion_Referencia((Parametro)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parametro), Lista[i]));

            Dr_Referencia = Dt_Referencia.NewRow();
            Dr_Referencia["Value"] = Lista[i];
            Dr_Referencia["Descripcion"] = Resultado.ElementAt(0);
            Dt_Referencia.Rows.Add(Dr_Referencia);

        }
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help. I served the last code I hope I have implemented appropriately, in time served but I have another problem .

I have another method for the description of the enum value and the time to send the form does not accept conversion used with enum fixed .

```
  //Add this line<Parametro_Referencia>() where Parametro...
 public DataTable Carga_Referencias<Parametro_Referencia>() where Parametro_Referencia : struct, IConvertible 
    {
        DataTable Dt_Referencia = new DataTable();
        Dt_Referencia.Columns.Add("Nombre");
        Dt_Referencia.Columns.Add("Descripcion");
        DataRow Dr_Referencia = Dt_Referencia.NewRow();
        IEnumerable<string> Resultado;


        Type Tipo = typeof(Parametro_Referencia); //Here error mark , does not recognize the name of the parameter
        String[] Lista = Tipo.GetEnumNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Length; i++)
        {


            Resultado = Descripcion_Referencia((Parametro_Referencia)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parametro_Referencia), Lista[i]));


            Dr_Referencia = Dt_Referencia.NewRow();
            Dr_Referencia["Value"] = Lista[i];
            Dr_Referencia["Descripcion"] = Resultado.ElementAt(0);
            Dt_Referencia.Rows.Add(Dr_Referencia);

        }
```

in the line Resultado = Descripcion_Referencia((Parametro_Referencia)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parametro_Referencia), Lista[i])) I have a problem. doesn't recognaize this conversion.

The metoho to get the description is that.

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> Descripcion_Referencia(Enum Referencia)
    {
        var Descripcion = new List<string>();
        var Tipo = Referencia.GetType();
        var Nombre = Enum.GetName(Tipo, Referencia);
        var Campo = Tipo.GetField(Nombre);
        var Campo_Descripcion = Campo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);
        foreach (DescriptionAttribute Atributo in Campo_Descripcion)
        {
            Descripcion.Add(Atributo.Description);
        }
        return Descripcion;
    }
        return Dt_Referencia;
    }
```

You will know how to convert or correct shipping ?

Comment: "if I write `public void Cargar_Combo(enum Lista)` it indicate like mistake" does it give a compile error? what error does it give you? Did you mean to write `Cargar_Combo(Lista_Color color)`?

Comment: I'm sorry. What I mean is that brand shows or error. If I write public void Cargar_Combos (enum list ) text is underlined in red. Tooltip indicates the "Type Expected"

Comment: You **cannot** have `Method(enum parameterName)` you can have `Method(Enum parameterName)`. Accepting `System.Enum` as a parameter is usually worthless unless you have a method like your `Descripcion_Referencia`. You likely want `Cargar_Combo(Lista_Color color)` or `Cargar_Combo(Lista_Size size)`

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you very much .
The method " Cargar_Combo " want it to be generic . In the project several enum defined and this generic method wanna call you, send my list , reference or field enum , and return me a DataTable with all elements of enum ( name and description ) for use in a combo or select list so you can not call it that fixed and I want it more dynamic . you will have idea? ..... excuse my writing 'm very bad with English .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums are weird in C# - they're types, sort of, and C# doesn't let you pass types as arguments, really. I wrote something a little bit ago to convert enums to Dictionaries; maybe the example will help show you how to handle enum arguments. Took me a while to figure out myself :)

```
public class EnumConverter
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int> EnumToDict<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        Type enumType = typeof (TEnum);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enum.");
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum))
                   .Cast<TEnum>()
                   .ToDictionary(t => t.ToString(), t => t.ToInt32(null /* 'culture' */));
    }
}
```

(en español!)
En lugar de `ToDictionary`, se puede utilizar cualquier metodo que quieres. Tiene sentido?

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help. I served the last code I hope I have implemented appropriately, in time served but I have another problem . n the line IEnumerable<string> Resultado = Descripcion_Referencia((Parametro_Referencia)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parametro_Referencia), Lista[i])) I have a problem. doesn't recognaize this conversion.

I have another method for the description of the enum value and the time to send the form does not accept conversion used with enum fixed . Can you help me?